# Get last updated date of a Google Spreadsheets as JSON endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-sheets

I have a public Google Spreadsheets and I'd like to get the updated date of it with the JSON endpoint in Javascript.

Here is the JSON endpoint : https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1hrae_CqzDZjXR8CUs8d7_sqpit5WUk7sPv94nyHY1A4/1/public/basic?alt=json

You may see a date in `feed.updated.$t` (currently it is 2020-03-17T13:59:25.968Z : 17th march at 13:59).

But when I want to get it with Javascript, I always get the current date and time, and I don't understand why.

```js
const elDate = document.getElementById('date');
const elFormattedDate = document.getElementById('formatted-date');

$.getJSON('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1hrae_CqzDZjXR8CUs8d7_sqpit5WUk7sPv94nyHY1A4/1/public/basic?alt=json', function(data) {
    var date = data.feed.updated.$t;
    var formattedDate = new Date(date);
    elDate.innerHTML = date;
    elFormattedDate.innerHTML = formattedDate;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <ul>
    <li><b>Date</b> : <span id="date"></span></li>
    <li><b>Formatted date</b> : <span id="formatted-date"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question to make it clear.

### Explanation

Thank's to [@huytc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60736791/7160865), it became clear that there's no differences between calling the JSON endpoint from a browser than from a Javascript script. The difference in the dates was simply due to browser cache.

So to be clear, this JSON endpoint will always get you the current date, and not the date in which the spreadsheet was last updated.

### Workaround with an App Script

Despite the fact that [@Iamblichus's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60737840/7160865) workaround with the Google Drive API seems a lot cleaner, I find it a bit "overkill" just to get the last updated date, especially because it requires not only a API key but the all oAuth process.

As [@huytc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60736791/7160865) suggests, I used a trigger in an App Script to make it work. I created a new Sheet called "Informations", and used the following script :

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = s.getSheetByName('Informations');
  var date = new Date();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1);
  range.setValue(date);
}
```

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/ajot/88ca5377cbde7963c552) helped me a lot.

**References** :

- [App Script in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- [onEdit(e) trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Answer (score 3):

Every time you call the endpoint, the field `feed.updated.$t` gets updated (try refreshing a few times to see for yourself). That's why you're getting the current date. You did nothing wrong, it's just the way Google Sheets API works.

Comment: I just tried it with Postman and I'm getting the current date. What I don't understand is that I get the "real" date when reading the JSON endpoint with my browser.

Comment: @crtlf You mean you get the correct date when you use Postman?

Comment: No I get the current date, same as Javascript. I only get the correct date when looking at JSON with my browser.

Comment: @crtlf Well, that is the expected behavior. Whenever you call this API, the date will get updated to the current date. There's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @crtlf It gets updated even when you use your browser. Try clearing your cache, or use incognito mode.

Comment: I guess I'll have to use the Google Sheets API to get the correct date, if there's no other way. I found it a bit "overkill" just to get a date though.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, this sheet is updated once per 5 minutes, and you want to get when it is updated automatically (NOT when the API is called), right?

Comment: I want to get when the document was last edited by a user, like in the "Version history" section, e.g. https://i.imgur.com/fBiM74D.png

Comment: @crtlf In that case, I think you can try using triggers: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

Answer (score 2):

As @huytc said, every time you make a request to this endpoint, the `updated` time gets updated, so you will always get the current date, not the date in which the spreadsheet was last updated.

#### Workaround: Using Drive API:

In order to get the date in which this spreadsheet was last updated, you can use the [Revisions](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions) or the [Changes](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/changes/list) collection from Drive API (see the difference between both [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/change-overview)).

You can, for example, list all the Revisions associated with this file via [Revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list). You just have to provide the `id` of the file in your API request. As a response, you will get something along the following lines:

```
{
  "revisions": [
    {
      "modifiedTime": datetime,
      // ... rest of revision 1 properties
    },
    {
      "modifiedTime": datetime,
      // ... rest of revision 2 properties
    },
    // ... rest of revisions
    {
      "modifiedTime": datetime,
      // ... rest of last revision properties
    }    
  ],
  // ... rest of properties
}
```

The `modifiedTime` of the last revision in the response is the date you're looking for.

#### Reference:

- [Revisions.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/list)
- [Changes and revisions overview](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/change-overview)